# Node.js: calling an undefined function as object property goes unnoticed

Tags: javascript, node.js, strict

I did notice a worrysome behaviour with node.js (v4.0.0).

I have an object with functions, something like this:

```
var local = {};
local.myMethod = function() {
  console.log('here I am');
};
```

At a certain point in time I did comment out `myMethod()` for debugging purposes.
Some time later, I did call it again in my code, forgetting to remove comments from function definition:

```
...
var result = local.myMethod();
...
/*
local.myMethod = function() {
  console.log('here I am');
};
*/
```

When running that code, I got no compile nor runtime error, so I got mad catching the silly problem...

What I ask is: *Is this behaviour intended?
Should I use some pragma enforcing strictness, to avoid such problems?*

**UPDATE**
Sorry, this code does not reproduce the problem, I did shrink it too much...
I'm quite sure on some condition the problem shows, however: I have a warning set just before the call to the undefined function... The warning prints, and then the code continues without a notice...
The *undefined* function is called inside an [async](http://github.com/caolan/async).each() function, but I can't yet simplify my code enough to post it here... Keep trying...

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAOXVP0YUwREdpwylbz93HDbhrO7MT0b9sg

Comment: your post is not making much sense, i doubt this can happen when the application is loaded with the new code (without the method)

Comment: You're right, sorry... I did reduce too much my code to come to a simple example, sorry... I will better investigate to come to a really *not* working code... :-)

Comment: what ide are you using ?

Comment: If promises are involved, a promise could be swallowing this error.

Comment: @David Haim: no ide, terminal and editor.

Comment: @torazaburo: no promises, but I'm using async (https://github.com/caolan/async). Unfortunately I currently can't reproduce the problem in a simpler scenario... I'm sure on some condition the problem shows, however: I have a warning set just before the call to the undefined function... The warning prints, and then the code continues without a notice...